# How does BitSet's set method work with bits shifting to the left?

Tags: java, bitset

Java's `BitSet` class has a method `Set` that sets a single bit to 1 (=true). The method source code is as follows:

```
public void set(int bitIndex) {
    if (bitIndex < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("bitIndex < 0: " + bitIndex);

    int wordIndex = wordIndex(bitIndex);
    expandTo(wordIndex);

    words[wordIndex] |= (1L << bitIndex); // Restores invariants

    checkInvariants();
}
```

In addition to the checks, the method's core code is: `words[wordIndex] |= (1L << bitIndex)`. I can clearly see in the assignment that the left part is the specific word that holds the relevant bit. However, I don't understand how the right part (the shifting left of the bit index) cause the setting of the requested (and only it) bit to 1. Could you please explain?

Comment: It is ORing the bit in.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-Bitwise-Operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1L << bitIndex` produces a `long`, whose bits are all 0s, except for one of the bits. The position of the "1" bit is determined by `bitIndex`. For example, if `bitIndex` is 10, then the 11th least significant bit is 1.

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000
```

Because the 1 is shifted to the left 10 times. In general, the (`bitIndex` mod 64 + 1)th least significant bit is the "1" bit.

This [mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) is then bitwise OR'ed with whatever is in `words[wordIndex]`. Every bit in `words[wordIndex]` stays the same because they are OR'ed with 0, except for the one place where it is a "1" in the mask. That bit in `words[wordIndex]` will become "1" no matter what it was originally, due to how OR works.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts of interest: `1L << bitIndex` and `words[wordIndex] |=`.

The first part – `1L << bitIndex` – shifts a bit some number of spots. Here's a table showing how that plays out with a few different numbers of shifting.

| statement | decimal | binary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1L << 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1L << 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 1L << 2 | 4 | 100 |
| 1L << 3 | 8 | 1000 |
| 1L << 4 | 16 | 10000 |

The second part – `words[wordIndex] |=` – takes whatever value was already at `words[wordIndex]` and uses bitwise "or" to include whatever bit was isolated from above. If that bit was already set (for that word), this operation wouldn't change anything. If the bit was 0, the "or" operation (`|=`) would set the bit to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the left side is being ORed (`|`) with the bit and the right most bit (or the Least Significant Bit - LSB) is bit `0`. An `OR` operator will set the specified one bit(s) in the source, to the same bits in the target, leaving the other bits unchanged.  Here are some examples.

```
int bits = 1;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bits));
bits |= 0b100_0000_0000; // set bit 10 to 1.
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bits));
```

prints

```
1
10000000001
^
bit 10
```

or do it like this

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bits));
bits = 1;
// or it can be done this way.
bits |=  1<<10;  // 10 is the bitIndex in bits to set so it is shifted 
                 // left to that position and the result is as before
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bits));
```

prints

```
10000000001
^
bit 10
```